# it says 'TessBaseApi' cannot be resolved

Tags: android-studio, tesseract

I have build an app using this site http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/ but there is a problem with OCR.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The project bar in my project looks like this:

[image]

I've added tesseract folder as a module, so it does not show it in libraries folder.

If you have not done that, try right-clicking on your app folder -> Open Module Settings (at the bottom) -> Dependencies -> press on "+" -> 3. Module dependency -> choose ":libraries:tess-two" or ":libraries:tesseract" (for me its tess-two)

[image]

Hope this helps.